# Disaggregating weekly to daily data

Tags: r, time-series

I have some data that shows weekly total values, where each row shows total summed over the preceding 7 days:

```
   coll_wk       New_A  New_B
   <date>        <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 2020-07-10      464    748
 2 2020-07-17     1679   3098
 3 2020-07-24     2611   7040
 4 2020-07-31     2420   6643
 5 2020-08-07     2289   5836
 6 2020-08-14     2583   5995
 7 2020-08-21     2464   5531
 8 2020-08-28     2146   5611
 9 2020-09-04     1905   5368
10 2020-09-11     1425   4603
# ℹ 138 more rows
```

I would like to disaggregate this into daily values. I have no reason to believe there is a strong weekly cycle to the data, and a simple linear or cubic spline interpolation for the shape of the daily curve would suffice. More importantly, though, I want to ensure that the total value is correctly conserved, such that summing the 7 daily values up to each week's date will yield the weekly value in the original data.

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202201/deaggregating-a-time-series), I have tried using the `td` function from the `tempdisagg` package:

```
disagg_A <- tempdisagg::td((dat %>% select(-New_B)) ~ 1, to='daily', method='denton-cholette', conversion='sum')$values
```

This runs and produces something largely reasonable but with two issues:

1. Some of the disaggregated values are negative, which is impossible for this data, and I can't find an option to coerce only non-negative values
2. Manually checking the disaggregated daily values against the weekly values, it seems the totals disaggregated values sum *backward* rather than *forward*, i.e. the weekly values are being treated as totals over the 7 days *starting* with the week date rather than *ending* with it, and again I can't figure out how to change that.

Is there any way to resolve these two issues?